# Animating images in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm sorry I don't have any more information about this but I simply don't know what it is. I've been asked to copy some other design that was written in old techonology but wasn't given a source for this, just an example.

I think the way they did theirs was 2 images, when hovering it would switch to another image with more drop shadow.

Is there a way to do this with an image in css: https://i.imgur.com/k7oBR7g.gifv

Comment: One way would be using SVG images, then changing the position when being hovered in css. I think it can also be done in a plain image

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
img:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: translate(-2px,-2px);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be simply possible with images, place the images in one block and animate them on hover. Like:

**Html**

```
<div class="imgblk">
   <img src="img1" class="img">
   <img src="img2" class="img">
   <img src="img3" class="img">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgblk 
{ 
   /* style the image block as per your design */ 
}
.imgblk img 
{ 
   width:150px; 
   height:150px; 
   object-fit:cover: 
   transition:all ease .3s;
   display:inline-block:
   margin-right:5px;
}
.imgblk img:hover 
{
   transform: translate(-1px, -3px);
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px #333;
}
```

Or the better way, use Icons like font-awesome (http://fontawesome.io/icons/) instead of image

Hope this will help you.